# Drawing a histogram from a bash command output

Tags: bash

I have the following output:

```
2015/1/7    8
2015/1/8    49
2015/1/9    40
2015/1/10   337
2015/1/11   11
2015/1/12   3
2015/1/13   9
2015/1/14   102
2015/1/15   62
2015/1/16   10
2015/1/17   30
2015/1/18   30
2015/1/19   1
2015/1/20   3
2015/1/21   23
2015/1/22   12
2015/1/24   6
2015/1/25   3
2015/1/27   2
2015/1/28   16
2015/1/29   1
2015/2/1    12
2015/2/2    2
2015/2/3    1
2015/2/4    10
2015/2/5    13
2015/2/6    2
2015/2/9    2
2015/2/10   25
2015/2/11   1
2015/2/12   6
2015/2/13   12
2015/2/14   2
2015/2/16   8
2015/2/17   8
2015/2/20   1
2015/2/23   1
2015/2/27   1
2015/3/2    3
2015/3/3    2
```

And I'd like to draw a histogram

```
2015/1/7  ===
2015/1/8  ===========
2015/1/9  ==========
2015/1/10 ====================================================================
2015/1/11 ===
2015/1/11 =
...
```

Do you know if there is a bash command that would let me do that?

Comment: [bashplotlib](https://github.com/glamp/bashplotlib) is a nice solution

Comment: That is indeed one of the risks of providing links instead of self-contained answers. If [the deleted SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949332/in-terminal-ascii-histograms-tool) is useful, please post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lane 'print $F[0], "\t", "=" x ($F[1] / 5)' file
```

#### EXPLANATIONS:

- `-a` is an explicit `split()` in `@F` array, we get the values with `$F[n]`
- `x` is to tell perl to print a character N times
- `($F[1] / 5)` : here we get the number and divide it by 5 for a pretty print output (simple arithmetic)

Comment: `perl -lane 'print $F[0], "\t", $F[1], "\t", "=" x ($F[1] / 3 + 1)'` It looks really great :) thanks

Answer (score 18):

In `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/ (\d+)$/"="x$1/e' file
```

- `e` causes the expression to be evaluated, so I get `=` repeated using the value of `$1` (the number matched by `(\d+)`).
- You could do `"="x($1\/3)` instead of `"="x$1` to get shorter lines. (The `/` is escaped since we're in the middle of a substitution command.)

---

In `bash` (inspired from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349796/2072269)):

```
while read d n 
do 
    printf "%s\t%${n}s\n" "$d" = | tr ' ' '=' 
done < test.txt
```

- `printf` pads the second string using spaces to get a width of `$n`  (`%${n}s`), and I replace the spaces with `=`.
- The columns are delimited using a tab (`\t`), but you can make it prettier by piping to `column -ts'\t'`.
- You could use `$((n/3))` instead of `${n}` to get shorter lines.

---

Another version:

```
unset IFS; printf "%s\t%*s\n" $(sed 's/$/ =/' test.txt) | tr ' ' =
```

The only drawback I can see is that you'll need to pipe `sed`'s output to something if you want to scale down, otherwise this is the cleanest option. If there is a chance of your input file containing one of `[?*` you should lead the command w/ `set -f;`.

Comment: Bravo for showing a shell solution too.  Your Perl solution is very clean as well.

Comment: @mikeserv Wonderful! I always forget `%*s` even though it was the first `printf`-related trick I learnt in C programming.

Comment: The `printf(sed) | tr` version doesn't works here as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Natim here being where?

Comment: @mikeserv limitations in argument length perhaps?

Comment: Here being on my computer running bash 4.3.11. I've got this output: https://www.irccloud.com/pastebin/Vfb8KsNA

Comment: @Natim do you have an empty leading line?

Comment: @mikeserv `sed` can read from filenames given as arguments. O.o

Comment: @Natim - this whole convo finally makes sense to me - i didnt see the pastebin before. I missed a lot around this question, i guess. Anyway, im pretty sure your problem was `...%$*s` - you dont want that `$`expansion token - just `%*s`.

Comment: @mikeserv I didn't notice that typo!

Comment: Hmm, the solution in this only uses 'sort' and 'uniq': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044539/generating-histogram-from-file

Comment: @qneill so? It isn't even remotely graphical.

Answer (score 11):

Easy with `awk`

```
awk '{$2=sprintf("%-*s", $2, ""); gsub(" ", "=", $2); printf("%-10s%s\n", $1, $2)}' file

2015/1/7 ========
2015/1/8 =================================================
2015/1/9 ========================================
..
..
```

Or with my favourite programming language

```
python3 -c 'import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  data, width = line.split()
  print("{:<10}{:=<{width}}".format(data, "", width=width))' <file
```

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
#! /bin/bash
histo="======================================================================+"

read datewd value

while [ -n "$datewd" ] ; do
   # Use a default width of 70 for the histogram
   echo -n "$datewd      "
   echo ${histo:0:$value}

   read datewd value
done
```

Which produces:

```
~/bash $./histogram.sh < histdata.txt
2015/1/7    ========
2015/1/8    =================================================
2015/1/9    ========================================
2015/1/10   ======================================================================+
2015/1/11   ===========
2015/1/12   ===
2015/1/13   =========
2015/1/14   ======================================================================+
2015/1/15   ==============================================================
2015/1/16   ==========
2015/1/17   ==============================
2015/1/18   ==============================
2015/1/19   =
2015/1/20   ===
2015/1/21   =======================
2015/1/22   ============
2015/1/24   ======
2015/1/25   ===
2015/1/27   ==
2015/1/28   ================
2015/1/29   =
2015/2/1    ============
2015/2/2    ==
2015/2/3    =
2015/2/4    ==========
2015/2/5    =============
2015/2/6    ==
2015/2/9    ==
2015/2/10   =========================
2015/2/11   =
2015/2/12   ======
2015/2/13   ============
2015/2/14   ==
2015/2/16   ========
2015/2/17   ========
2015/2/20   =
2015/2/23   =
2015/2/27   =
2015/3/2    ===
2015/3/3    ==
~/bash $
```

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like that with the [bar](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-verbs.html#bar) verb in [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ mlr --nidx --repifs --ofs tab bar -f 2 file
2015/1/7    ***.....................................
2015/1/8    *******************.....................
2015/1/9    ****************........................
2015/1/10   ***************************************#
2015/1/11   ****....................................
2015/1/12   *.......................................
.
.
.
```

Comment: Miller is new to me. It is very cool!

Comment: Could you please explain a little more what does each parameter do? Even reading the [reference](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html) is not clear to me

Comment: Didn't know about Miller until today. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

(this is not exactly what you ask, but) With Gnuplot, if you are in X, try:

```
gnuplot -p -e 'set sty d hist;set xtic rot; plot "file" u 2:xtic(1)'
```

[image]

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for. Thank you ! I would have appreciated to know if it can read stdin. and a quick word about data representation.

Comment: @mh-cbon, gnuplot can do manyyyy diferent things (see their docs and demos). Example with stdin `seq 30 | gnuplot -p -e 'set style d hist; plot "-" u ($1**3) `. You can also use `"/dev/stdin"'

Comment: oh thank you ! I am pretty aware it is very powerful, but i admit i have not yet found whatsneeded to learn it. A good resource, a topic to work with, motivation. For now, i have resorted to using a plotter written written with the Go language https://golangdocs.com/plotting-in-golang-histogram-barplot-boxplot But i definitely going to try your command.

Comment: there is something! But the scaling is bad. let me write a question ^^

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665243/improve-plot-scale-and-display if you want to take a look

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot

Answer (score 2):

This struck me as a fun traditional command line problem.  Here's my `bash` script solution:

```
awk '{if (count[$1]){count[$1] += $2} else {count[$1] = $2}} \
        END{for (year in count) {print year, count[year];}}' data |
sed -e 's/\// /g' | sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n |
awk '{printf("%d/%d/%d\t", $1,$2,$3); for (i=0;i<$4;++i) {printf("=")}; printf("\n");}'
```

The little script above assumes the data is in a file imaginatively named "data".

I'm not too happy with the "run it through sed and sort" line - it would be unnecessary  if your month and day-of-month always had 2 digits, but that's life.

Also, as a historical note, traditional Unixes used to come with a command line plotting utility that could do fairly ugly ASCII graphs and plots. I can't remember the name, but it looks like [GNU plotutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/) replace the old traditional utility.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if ($1 in count) ...`?

Comment: @muru - seems to work either way. However, I did find a typo in the "else" clause.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while read value count; do
    printf '%s:\t%s\n' "${value}" "$(printf "%${count}s" | tr ' ' '=')"
done <path/to/my-output
```

The only tricky part is the construction of the bar. I do it here by delegating to `printf` and `tr` like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash/5349796#5349796).

As a bonus, it's POSIX-`sh`-compliant.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash/5349796#5349796
- https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/printf/
- https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/tr/

Answer (score 1):

Nice exercise here.  I dumped the data in a file called "data" because I am very imaginative.

Well, you asked for it in bash...  here it is in pure bash.

```
cat data | while read date i; do printf "%-10s " $date; for x in $(seq 1 $i); do echo -n "="; done; echo; done
```

awk is a better option.

```
awk '{ s=" ";while ($2-->0) s=s"=";printf "%-10s %s\n",$1,s }' data
```

Comment: Can you pipe the data through awk instead of using a file?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing either way.  Just add a "cat data |" at the beginning like I had for the bash bits, or a "<data" at the end.  Or you can even just have the awk part without a file specified, paste in the data and hit ctrl-D at the end.  Specifying the file just treats that file as stdin, and I didn't want to keep copying and pasting the datafile because I'm lazy.

Comment: Actually, I just reread the question while linking this to a coworker...  you said you had "output", not a data file.  So you can just run whatever is creating that report, then pipe it to awk, and you're done.  Pipes just direct output of the last command as the source of input for the next command.