# improve plot scale and display

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot some data using `gnuplot`

My input is similar to

```
$ go run . | tail
410ms-420ms 14260
420ms-430ms 13654
430ms-440ms 13344
440ms-450ms 13156
450ms-460ms 12829
460ms-470ms 12463
470ms-480ms 12883
480ms-490ms 12100
490ms-500ms 11902
500ms-510ms 11643
```

The length of the dataset is `51`

My command is

```
go run . | gnuplot -p -e 'set style d hist; set style fill solid; plot "-" u 2:xtic(1) linecolor 'black'   title "Counts by duration"'
```

My program, for those who have the Go language available is https://play.golang.org/p/DAIEY1YZ7LT

My output is like

[image]

How can i improve the display so it is readable by an human ?

Is it possible to show only a subsets of labels in the x axis ?

Can the bottom indicator of pointer x y positions show the label instead of x value ?

Comment: I would like to get the duration as expressed by the source, in text `110ms`, and their counts as the height of the bar. i guess...

Comment: i would like to display the data with other kind of plots too.